# What is the definition of a Majorana fermion in conformal field theory?

Tags: conformal-field-theory, dirac-equation, spinors, majorana-fermions, clifford-algebra

### Majorana spinors background

According to Eq. (4.84) and (4.85) of [these notes](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft.html), charge conjugation of the spinor $\Psi$ is defined as

$$ \Psi^{(c)} = C \Psi^*,$$

where $C$ is the unitary charge conjugation matrix that obeys $C^\dagger \gamma^\mu C = -(\gamma^\mu)^*$ for all gamma matrices. According to Eq. (4.87) Majorana spinor obeys $ \Psi^{(c)} = \Psi$.

### My question

I am reading section 2.9.2 on page 56 of *An Introduction to Conformal Field Theory by Blumenhagen and Plauschinn* where the authors introduce a free Majorana fermion $\Psi = (\psi, \bar{\psi} )^T$ in $(1+1)$D Minkowski space. It is stated that with the two-dimensional gamma matrices

$$ \gamma^0 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} , \quad \gamma^1 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix},$$

the Majorana condition is that the components $\psi, \bar{\psi}$ of the spinor $\Psi$ are *real*. I cannot show this.

The gamma matrices can be written in terms of the Pauli matrices as $\gamma^0 = \sigma^x$ and $\gamma^1 = i \sigma^y$. Therefore, our charge conjugation matrix requires

$$ \begin{align} C^\dagger \sigma^x C & = -\sigma^x, \\  C^\dagger (i \sigma^y) C & = -i \sigma^y \quad \Rightarrow \quad C^\dagger \sigma^y C = -\sigma^y \end{align}$$

Therefore, I can take $C = \sigma^z$ as it indeed obeys these relations. Applying this to the spinor from the book, I have

$$ \Psi^{(c)} = \sigma^z \Psi^* = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \psi \\ \bar{\psi} \end{pmatrix}^* = \begin{pmatrix} \psi^* \\ - \bar{\psi}^* \end{pmatrix}.  $$

If I took $\psi, \bar{\psi}$ to be real as the book insists, then $\Psi^{(c)} \neq \Psi$ so it is not Majorana. In fact, I would expect that if the reality of the components means the spinor is Majorana, then $C = \mathbb{I}$. However, this does not obey the required properties of $C$ as our representation is not imaginary. Is this an error in the book? I have seen this used on page 34 of [these notes](http://edu.itp.phys.ethz.ch/fs13/cft/SM2_Molignini.pdf). Am I missing something here?

Comment: this looks like it has to do with metric signature. If you make your matrices imaginary (multiply by $i$), then the signature becomes $-1,+1$ instead of $+1,-1$. In this signature the matrix is indeed $C=\mathbb I$. So perhaps the author is using the opposite signature? Or they are not being self-consistent?